# How do I get a PHP variable between single quotes?

Tags: php, facebook, fbjs

How can I get the value `$fbAppPath` into the PHP statement below?

```
<? print json_encode(array(array('text' => 'Become A Fan', 'href' => '$fbAppPath'))); ?>
```

Comment: The question is valid because it is conceivable the coder would want to concatenate `'$fbAppPath'` with a string literal. There are three constructive solutions offered here:
- Remove the single quote altogether (e.g., Matthew),
- Substitute the single quote marks with double quote marks (e.g. odonnell),
- Concatenate the string (e.g., Chacha102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<? print json_encode(array(array('text' => 'Become A Fan', 'href' => $fbAppPath))); ?>`

Answer (score 8):

You cannot get a variable in a single quote string. PHP interprets all single-quoted strings EXACTLY as they appear. (aside from escaping a single quote)

The ONLY way to get a variable while using single quotes is to break out of them:

```
$foo = 'variable';
echo 'single-quoted-string-'.$foo.'-more-single-quoted-string';
```

Comment: Note that you can use single quotes inside double quotes and still parse the variable `<?php $test = 'test'; echo "This is a '$test'.";`.

Answer (score 4):

Or

```
<? print json_encode(array(array('text' => 'Become A Fan', 'href' => "more text ${fbAppPath} more text"))); ?>
```

if you wanted to embed the variable value in a string.  The double quotes are important in that case.

Answer (score -3):

You do not need quotes around a variable that is already a string.

```
'I am a string, because I am surrounded by quotes';

$string = 'I am a string, because I am surrounded by quotes';
if (is_string($string)) {
    echo 'Yes, the variable $string is a string, because it contains a string';
}

$anotherString = $string;
if (is_string($anotherString)) {
    echo 'The variable $anotherString is a string as well, because it contains a string as well';
}

$notWhatYouExpect = '$string';
echo $notWhatYouExpect;  // outputs the word '$string'
```

Comment: Your code demonstrates the failure of placing a variable between single quotes. You might want to actually test your code and see for yourself.

Comment: @Gregory Because the question is nonsense. The answer here is not to "get a variable between single quotes" at all.

Comment: The question is not nonsense. If there is no answer, then say so. That's what a question is for. A question is not nonsense merely based on the absence of a solution. And if there is no solution, you would not need to provide code that gives the impression of a solution, sorry.

Comment: @Gregory Sorry if you fail to see my answer. Maybe I should have expressed it more clearly. The answer is: *"you do not need quotes around a variable that is already a string"*, followed by code that demonstrates this point, specifically with `$anotherString = $string` and `$notWhatYouExpect = ...`.

Comment: That is true enough, but I arrived at this page because I had the same question as the OP. I thought there was an answer, something like: `'You are number ${count}'` or `'You are number {$count}'` but those didn't work. The only answer that does work, and it's the answer the OP would have to live with, is: `'You are number' . $count`

Comment: @Gregory Nope, the answer is to use *double quotes* (`"`) if you want variable interpolation. See the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing But in the case of the OP, where the variable is the only thing inside the "string", this is entirely pointless, which my answer is pointing out.